# select Two Employee Names from a single table with two different employee Ids in a single stored procedure

Tags: sql

I am trying to solve this below query from one day but i didn't get the out put..

Query is:

```
select distinct L.LeadBudget,L.CompanyName,L.LeadTitle,L.Status,
E.Name as OwnerName,E.Name as 
CreatedUser
 from Leads L,Employee E where L.LeadId='2' 
 and E.EmployeeId=L.LeadOwner and E.EmployeeId=L.CreatedUserId
```

In The above query i want to get

```
E.Name as OwnerName and E.Name as CreatedUser 
from a single Employee tables)..where E.EmployeeId=L.LeadOwner and 
E.EmployeeId=L.CreatedUserId
```

if i execute with out OwnerName or Created User i am getting the data..but i want to get both the names.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are exactly asking for, but I think
´L.Name as OwnerName,E.Name as CreatedUser´ is what you are trying to do.

Comment: i don't have Name in L table..i have only employee Id's...owner name and created user both are employee id's in L table...

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use a more modern JOIN style; instead of listing multiple talbes and doing everything in the WHERE.
Basically to achiev what you want to do you will need to perform a JOIN for both employees.

```
SELECT l.LeadBudget, l.CompanyName, l.LeadTitle, l.Status, leadEmp.Name As OwnerName, createdEmp.Name As CreatedUser
FROM Leads l
     INNER JOIN Employee leadEmp ON(l.LeadOwner = leadEmp.EmployeeId)
     INNER JOIN Employee createdEmp ON(l.CreatedUserId= createdEmp.EmployeeId)
WHERE l.LeadId='2'
```

Comment: Thank a lot it's worked for me...thank you all for helping me to solve this issue

Comment: In that case I would appreciate it very much if you makred the question as solved by selecting an (my ;) ) answer.